# How can I force a period at the end of a note in a tufte-book citation?

Tags: bibtex, citing, tufte, bibentry

In tufte-book, citations are rendered as sidenotes, which is great. However, the note field of a bibtex citation is not processed correctly in the sidenote:

.tex file:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\begin{document}
Some text, with a citation~\cite{testcite}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{tmpdoc}
\end{document}
```

.bib file:

```
@book{testcite,
  title={The},
  author={Book},
  year={1998},
  publisher={Pub},
  edition={second},
  note={Part 2.}
}
```

Truncated output with tufte-book as the document class:

[image]

Output with article as the document class:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tufte-book` uses the package `bibentry` which always deletes the final period.  You have two options:

1. Protect the final dot in the note field:

   ```
   @book{testcite,
    title={The},
    author={Book},
    year={1998},
    publisher={Pub},
    edition={second},
    note={Part 2{.}}
   }
   ```
2. Make `bibentry` to always keep the final period by redefining `\BR@nodot` (the command that strips the dot).  Add to the preamble:

   ```
   \makeatletter
   \def\BR@nodot#1.\relax#2\relax{#1.}
   \makeatother
   ```