# How to end a citation note with a period except when it ends with a URL in tufte-book class?

Tags: bibtex, citing, bibentry, tufte-book

I have a book that I am working on using the `tufte-book` class. I made a customized bibliography style file that ends a citation with a period at the end, except when the citation ends with a URL. Every citation appears correctly when I use the `article` class. When I switch to `tufte-book` class, I get all the citations just fine, except the period is missing at the end.

Based on the information from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148585/how-can-i-force-a-period-at-the-end-of-a-note-in-a-tufte-book-citation), I added the code

```
\makeatletter
\def\BR@nodot#1.\relax#2\relax{#1.}
\makeatother
```

which solve the problem of adding the missing period at the end of every citation, except it adds a period at the end of the URL too which does not respect the bibliography style file.

To be specific, certain entry types do not end with a period, such as `@webpage`, `@url`, etc.

How do I solve this problem? Or how do I just disable the period removing feature of `bibentry` package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I emailed the author of the `bibentry` package Patrick W. Daly and I got the solution that I was looking for, just a slight modification of the code given in the question:

```
\makeatletter
\def\BR@nodot#1.\relax#2\relax{#1#2}
\makeatother
```